# Deeplearning4J-- java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, netbeans, out-of-memory, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to load Google news corpus using this code:

```
           File gModel = new File("/word2vec/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz");
Word2Vec vec = WordVectorSerializer.loadGoogleModel(gModel, true);
```

but it causes this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to change VM options parameters like it explained in official documenatation of deeplearning4j with:

```
         -Xms1024m -Xmx10g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

Comment: I'll assume you're using a 64 bit JDK 7 and that the machine has > 10G physical memory available.  You might think about changing to JDK 8.  Perm space is gone - it uses meta space.

Comment: for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac.exe     .. the JDK that i'm using.. should i change it ?

Comment: JDK 8 looks fine.  Is it a 64 bit version running on a 64 bit Windows operating system?  Do you have more than 10GB of physical memory installed and available?

Comment: it's 64 bit windows.. no i dont have 10 .. there is no other solution ?

Comment: Seems silly to ask for more memory than is available.  You have to leave enough for OS, etc.  JDK 8 doesn't have perm space; it's meta space.  You should investigate increasing the size of your meta space.  Don't go for something that large at first.  Do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

I found this as I ran in a similar issue. I noticed this was never answered and I wonder if anyone cares. However, setting these VM arguments did it for me (I have 8G physical memory):

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx6g -XX:MaxPermSize=6g
```